# Python 2.7: find integer strings in file using regex & add them: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to read a .txt file (data is ASCII textbook material stuff) with strings of numbers scattered throughout the file.  I'm trying to extract those numbers to tag them to a list using regex and eventually add all the values as integers into a sum variable and print it.  The problem is when I run this code:

```
import re

hand = open('regexTextData.txt')
numbers = list()
for line in hand:
        if len(line) == 0: continue
        extractedNumbers = re.findall('[0-9+]', line)
        numbers = extractedNumbers + numbers

total = 0
for i in range(len(numbers)):
        value = int(numbers[i])
        total = total + value

print(total)
```

I run into an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sum_numbers_in_text_regex.py", line 13, in <module>
    value = int(numbers[i]) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'
```

What exactly went wrong here?  I tried looking at other solutions but to no avail.  If I missed a page that covered it I would like to know please.

Thanks ahead of time for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for n in range(len(numbers)):
```

not

```
for n in len(numbers):
```

FINAL EDIT:  FINISHED PROGRAM

```
import re

hand = open('regexTextData.txt')
numbers = [] # no need of writing out list(), just use []
for line in hand:
        if len(line) == 0: continue
        extractedNumbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', line) # Do not use '+' as that matches the '+' symbols.
        numbers = extractedNumbers + numbers

total = 0
for i in range(len(numbers)):
        value = int(numbers[i]) # Now all your values in numbers should be in numerical string form.
        total = total + value

print(total)
```

Just needed to change the regex pattern to '([0-9]+)' and it would recognize all strings with numbers.  This fixed the program.

Your main problem was the regex.
Let's say we had some example text as `line = "0 and 1 and 2 and 2 + and yes mate"`

```
re.findall('[0-9+]', line) # Outputs: ['0', '1', '2', '2', '+']. We have matched a '+' because you have include the plus symbol in your regex.
```

Solution (remove +):

```
re.findall('([0-9]+)', line) # Outputs: ['0', '1', '2', '2'] # No more '+'.
```

BONUS:
If you are interested, you can also replace this code:

```
total = 0
for i in range(len(numbers)):
        value = int(numbers[i]) # Now all your values in numbers should be in numerical string form.
        total = total + value
```

with this simplified code:

```
total = sum(map(lambda x: int(x), numbers))
```

`lambda` is an anonymous function that takes `x` as input and outputs `int(x)`. `map` is a function where it applies a function (our lamda function) on each element of `numbers`. Finally, `sum` will simply add up the numbers found in an iterable (after applying the `map` function which returns an iterable, we will have integers only).

I like the solution you posted and it is probably more efficient but for the purposes of understanding regex I need to use regex.  Appreciate the alternative solution though.

Comment: thanks.  I totally mistyped and fixed the past error.  What is wrong now though?

Comment: Your `numbers` does not have a list of numerical strings. Please see my edited answer for the new solution.

Comment: I understand the list of numerical strings but the numbers are greater than 1 digit sometimes.  "37820" might be an example of a numerical string you would see in this txt file.  Sorry for not being more specific!

Comment: last edit finished the program.  Thank you for your help in identifying the source of the problem your explanation was very clear

Comment: No worries - i just made a change to regex code. It will not match digits that have a length greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate an integer. Instead, try iterating a range:

```
for n in range(len(numbers)):
    value = int(numbers[n])
    sum = sum + value
```

Also note the change from `numbers[i]` to `numbers[n]`.

Comment: thanks.  I totally mistyped and fixed the past error.  What is wrong now though?